# Release build with R8 not excluding classes

Tags: android, android-r8

I'm facing some issues when compiling the release version of my app.

I'm currently using Room and I have my model classes are under:

```
com.example.room.entity
```

and in order to let the app working I'm using a proguard rule

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*,SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class com.example.room.entity.**.* { *; }
```

Once I build the version and I execute on my phone the app crash and I can see

> Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
> com.roommate.example.room.entity.UserEntity

The output of -printusage shows me that the the class I'm trying to preserve is somewhat touched by R8.

What can I do to enforce my rules?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change second line to:

```
-keep class com.roommate.example.room.entity.** { *; }
```

Comment: So the problem could be the final .* part? There is a particular reason?

Comment: @MatteoBucci Ah, no, the problem is that you're keeping the classes in `-keep class com.example.room.entity.**.* { *; }` whereas your code is actually living in `com.roommate.example.room.entity.UserEntity` (note the com.roommate at the start, as opposed to com.example...)